# JMockit mocked class returns null for child method

Tags: unit-testing, jmockit

I want to test a filter that implements ContainerRequestFilter from JAX-RS.

The implementation class is:

```
public class CookieRequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

public static final String EXCLUDE_FROM_FILTER = ".*healthy$|.*alive$";

@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
    URI uri = requestContext.getUriInfo().getAbsolutePath();
    if (uri.getPath().matches(EXCLUDE_FROM_FILTER)) {
        return;
    }
    Cookie cookie = requestContext.getCookies().get("cookie_identifier");
    // some other code here
}
}
```

The unit tests are run using JMockit framework.
The test is:

```
@RunWith(JMockit.class)
public class CookieRequestFilterTest {

@Tested
private CookieRequestFilter cookieRequestFilter;

@Test
public void filterCookie(@Mocked ContainerRequestContext request) throws IOException {
    Map<String, Cookie> cookies = new HashMap<>();
    String identifier = "1";
    cookies.put("cookie_identifier", getCookie(identifier));
    new Expectations() {{
        request.getCookies();
        times = 1;
        result = cookies;
    }};

    cookieRequestFilter.filter(request);
}

private NewCookie getCookie(String value) {
    return new NewCookie("cookie_identifier",
                         value,
                         "/",
                         "",
                         1,
                         null,
                         840,
                         new Date(new Date().getTime() + 840 * 1000),
                         true,
                         false);
}
}
```

It gives me a NPE at

> uri.getPath().matches(EXCLUDE_FROM_FILTER)

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Note the test doesn't match with the method being tested (it records `getCookies()`, but a different method is called in `filter`).

Comment: the `getCookies()` method is called bellow but I didn't provide the code